# Using API Keys: When and when not to use

Tags: javascript, youtube-data-api

I am using JavaScript and I am not entirely sure what I am doing.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#http-request

1. I was told that I had to use a key, but when I scroll down to the example, they are not using a key, why?
2. When are you required/not required to use an API key?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you check out the GO and Java examples, they do make use of a key. For example, the GO example has:

   ```
   ...
   const developerKey = "YOUR DEVELOPER KEY"

   func main() {
       flag.Parse()

       client := &http.Client{
               Transport: &transport.APIKey{Key: developerKey},
   }
   ...
   ```

   You can see they provide a placeholder for your API key. The APPS examples don't make use of a key, likely because they expect a separate authentication script to run. For example, Google has an `auth.js` that is needed for JavaScript.
2. Any time you send a request to an API, you will need to be authenticated in some way. This authentication lets the owner of the API properly limit how many requests are made against the API, what data is given, and what parts of the API are visible. Keys are just one way of authentication.

Comment: I am new to API's and writing code in general, so I appreciate the help. 
This answers my question, thank you very much!